# HCf of Polynomials over field extensions

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

This is actually a theorem from my lecture notes and it says:

**Suppose $L/K$ is  field extension, and $f,g$ $\in$ $K[X]$. Then gcd($f,g$) = $1$ in $K[X]$ if and only if gcd($f,g$) = $1$ in $L[X]$**

The proof in the lecture notes is just some lines on how the euclidean algorithm, which computes the gcd doesn't take into account the coefficients of the polynomials, but I would like to see if there is a mathematical proof for this statement.

I don't quite see how the statement would work, for e.g., suppose f and g have only one common factor ($x$-$\alpha$), where $\alpha$ $\in$ L, then surely the hcf of f, g in K[X] is 1 and in L[X] is ($x$-$\alpha$).

(Or is it me that has got the concept of hcf wrong? The above statement obviously assumes that for two polynomials in K[X] to have a factor, the common factor must also be in K[x].?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euclidean Algorithm argument that you refer to is quite mathematical.  Alternately, you can use the fact that if $f$ and $g$ are relatively prime polynomials in $K[X]$, then there are polynomials $u$ and $v$ in $K[X]$ such that $fu+gv=1$ (the Bezout "Identity"). This forces $f$ and $g$ to be relatively prime when considered as polynomials in $L[X]$.

Your "$x-\alpha$" argument assumes that $\alpha$ is the *only* common root of $f$ and $g$ in $L$.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, and your proof is probably quite a good way to prove the statement. But with the "($x$-$\alpha$)" argument, even if we take away the assumption that $\alpha$ is the ONLY common root, then still we would have hcf  of $f,g$ $\neq$ $1$?

Comment: What will happen is that if you try to produce examples with $\alpha\not\in K$, there will be additional roots, in the simplest case one additional root $x-\bar{\alpha}$, and $(x-\alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha})$ will be a polynomial with coefficients in $K$ that divides both $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Hmm, I think I need to think this through better. Finally, when we are indeed calculating the factors of two polynomials, suppose they have a common factor $h$, then let $f $ =  $h.m$, for some polynomial m. Then does m have to be in K[X]?

Comment: Let us take an easy example, $K$ the rationals, $L=K[\sqrt{2}]$. The polynomials $(X^2+1)(X^2-2)$ and $(X^2+5)(X^2-2)$ have the common factor $h=X-\sqrt{2}$ in $L[X]$, and $m$ is not in $K[X]$. But "the" **greatest** common factor is $h=X^2-2$, and for that $h$, $m\in K[X]$.